# Laravel mysql create table on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to dynamicly create a database and then create table in that database

```
// Create DB
DB::connection('mysql-group')->statement(
    'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `' . $new_db_name . '`'
);

// Change DB
Config::set($prefix . '.database', $new_db_name);
DB::connection('mysql-group')->setDatabaseName($new_db_name);
DB::connection('mysql-group')->reconnect();

Log::debug(DB::connection('mysql-group')->getDatabaseName());

// Create Table
$table_schema = file_get_contents(base_path('resources/table_schema.sql'));
$split = explode("# --\n", $table_schema);

foreach( $split as $sth ) {
    DB::connection('mysql-group')->select(DB::raw($sth));
}
```

The file table_schema.sql look like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `eid` (`eid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
# --
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2`  (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `eid` (`eid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
# --
```

But the problem is, the error kept comming out:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 (SQL: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`  (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `eid` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `eid` (`eid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; )
```

I tried adding this in the front, but the result is same

```
DB::connection('mysql-group')->statement(
    'SET SESSION wait_timeout=65535'
);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: DB::connection('mysql-group')->select(DB::raw($sth)); I dont know if I am right, but you are selecting (->select()), try query, not select

Comment: I solved it by changing select() to statement()

Comment: This works for Laravel 4.2. @jeremy5189 Could you create an answer with your update and accept it. I nearly missed your comment and went back to Google.